# {% if user.is_authenticated %} for specific user only

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am using : `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`  to check if people are logged in, so I can set the navbar links depending on logged in or not.

I want to make navbar links special for admin user. So there has to be a check not just if that user is authenticated, but also if that authenticated user is an Admin.

I was thinking about something like
`{% if user(Admin).is_authenticated %}`
but that didn't work.

Somebody got an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django uses .is_staff and .is_superuser for these checks. See more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser). `is_superuser` checks the boolean field in the django user module.

try

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
```

Comment: Thanks, {% if user.is_admin %}  did not work, when i looked at the db i  saw that admin has Staff Status. So i tried {% if user.is_staff %}  and that worked like a charm. Cheers

Comment: Oops, yes that is my fault. This would be `is_superuser`

Comment: Updated the answer. If you find it to be the answer you used, please mark it as correct to help other users in the community.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend your condition

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_admin %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
    {% if usr.is_superuser %}
    Do something here for the superuser
    {% endif %}
    {% if usr.is_authenticated %}
    Do something for those who are authenticated
    {% else %}
    Do something for those who did not authenticate
    {% endif %}
```